# use Scalene for FastAPI profiling

Tags: python, profiling, profiler, scalene

I'm currently trying to profile my FastAPI endpoints using Scalene. my code looks like this. I have a profiling middleware like this:

```py
class ScaleneProfilerMiddleware(BaseHTTPMiddleware):

    def __init__(self, app):
        super().__init__(app)

    async def dispatch(self, request: Request, call_next):
        with _profiler() as profiler:
            response = await call_next(request)
            return _handle_response(profiler)
```

and the **_profiler()** function should be something like this:

```py
@contextmanager
def _profiler():
    profiler = Scalene()
    try:
        profiler.start()
        yield profiler
    finally:
        profiler.stop()
```

and I like to generate an HTML response right away using the **_handle_response(response, profiler)** which is something like this:

```py
def _handle_response(
    profiler: Scalene
) -> Response:
    return HTMLResponse(profiler.generate_html())
```

I couldn't find any example like this so I'm wondering if this is possible at the moment

Comment: What exactly is your question? Have you tried running your code? Does it work?

Comment: No, it does not work it's a kind of pseudocode. my question is "is there a way to use scalene like this and generate an HTML response right away?" @M.O.